# Wonder-twin power "Zoom to rectangle" activate?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image]

Is there a way to have the "Zoom to rectangle" tool automatically activated by default when a matplotlib figure is shown?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = np.arange(-300, 300)
y = x**2-7*x
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
plt.plot(x, y)
# Add something here to activate the "Zoom to rectangle" tool?
plt.show()
```

Comment: This will probably be backend-dependent.  Which backend do you use? To be clear, I don't know the answer. :)

Comment: I was wrong with my first comment: http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/backend_bases_api.html#matplotlib.backend_bases.NavigationToolbar2.zoom  Don't know on which object this method must be called, though.

Comment: I'm using GtkAgg, in case that matters.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
plt.get_current_fig_manager().toolbar.zoom()
```